# How to make combinations faster in python

Tags: python, combinations

I am writing a code in python in which I need all possible combinations of up to 1000 elements and then perform multiple actions on them. Is there any way to reduce the run time. By using itertools the run time is in minutes after just 50 elements.
Currently I am using this code (I have commented out the print statement because it significantly increases the run time):

```
import itertools
import time

def all_combos_func(arguments):
    data = list(arguments)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(data, r) for r in range(len(data)+1))

start_time = time.time()

all_comb= []
for i in range (1000):
    all_comb.append(i+1)
all_combos = all_combos_func(all_comb)
all_combos_count = []
for i in all_combos:
    all_combos_count.append(i)
    # print(i)
print("this is the total length", len(all_combos_count))
end_time = time.time()

print(end_time-start_time)
```

Comment: show your code :)

Comment: I added it here

Comment: its just expensive to do this .. .you probably need to find some way to narrow your search space

Comment: Is there any other way to get all combinations that is more time efficient?

Comment: As an addon to what has been said: 2^1000 is an impossibly large list. Not only could your computer not process all these combinations before the end of the universe, nor could it store that many values in memory, but python as a language is not even capable of addressing something of this size. If you can say *why* you need to do this, maybe we can point you in the right direction for a more efficient way.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I basically have a list of metals from which I have to create an alloy. So i have to figure out which elements to use and in how much quantity. That is why I was trying to generate these combinations.

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> len(all_combos_func(range(0))
1
>>> len(all_combos_func(range(1))
2
>>> len(all_combos_func(range(2))
4
>>> len(all_combos_func(range(3))
8
>>> len(all_combos_func(range(4))
16
```

Your `all_combos_func` is returning `2^(len(input))` combinations. So when you ask for all combinations and you pass in a 1000 element list, you get back 2^1000 results. Yeah, it's gonna take a while.

2^1000 = 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376